# Can I install an SSD into a hard disk drive bracket labelled as SATA AHCI

Tags: ssd, sata

I have a [2.5 inch Kingston internal SSD](https://www.kingston.com/us/ssd/q500-solid-state-drive), and Inspiron 5590 laptop whose [manual](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/inspiron-15-5590-laptop_users-guide_en-us.pdf) says

> “2.5-inch hard drive SATA AHCI, up to 6 Gbps”

Is compatible with the device, in its hard disk drive slot. I want to know if I can install this SSD into this slot, since it also has a SATA port.

I have no idea about this AHCI, but I really want to know if the things can go right. Please give advice.

Comment: SSD's are no different than spinning hard drives as far as interchangeability, Yes you can.

Comment: That's precisely what I thought. But today, I contacted Dell and the guy who spoke to me said this can't be done, but I was doubtful if he was professional or just a usual agent.

Comment: It will work, I have upgraded hundreds of laptops to ssd's.

Comment: Those SSD drives are shaped the same as hard disk drives for the exact purpose you are engaged in: Upgrading away from hard disk drives. So whoever that Dell rep was, they sound less than support and more like sales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, you can usually install a **2.5 inch SATA SSD** in a **2.5 inch bay** which was originally **meant for HDDs**.

Since this is a SATA3 port (6 Gbps) this is the fastest you can get out of a SATA SSD today  anyway and you are not bottlenecked by the connector in the laptop only (since the SSD is SATA3 as well).

The other way around seems a bit more complicated than a simple yes, since HDDs might be thicker and/or might draw to much power (since the platters need to physically move), but putting a SSD in an HDD-bay should not make any problems.